# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined" and similarly for other array functions like map using ReactJS and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am following a tutorial and when at this point I'm getting stuck. It gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` when  I try to filter through the Product array. I was implementing the same functionality using Axios according to the tutorial and it was working. The instructor then changed to redux and I followed the same steps and that's when I got the error. I'm pretty new to React and completely new to Axios and Redux and I've been trying to find out what's wrong but I'm getting nowhere.

Here's my ProductScreens.jsx where the error occurs:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Rating from "../Components/rating.jsx";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { listProducts } from "../actions/productActions.js"

function Sale({product}){
        if("salePrice" in product){
                return <li>Sale Price: ₹{product.salePrice}</li>;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
export default function ProductsScreen(props){
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const productList = useSelector( state => state.productList);
        const {loading,error,products} = productList;
        useEffect(() =>{
                dispatch(listProducts());
        },[dispatch]);
        const product = products.filter(prod => prod.category === props.match.params.category && prod.subcategory === props.match.params.subcategory);
        return (
        <div className="container-fluid main-cards">
                <div className="row">
                {
                    product.map(product => (
                        <div key={product._id} className="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 main-card-item">
                            <div className="card">
                                <a href={`/product/${product._id}`}><img src={product.mainImage} className="card-img-top" alt="..."></img></a>
                                <div className="card-body product-card list-group">
                                    <h5 className="card-title">{product.name}</h5>
                                    <p className="card-text">{product.description}</p>
                                    <ul className="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                                            <li>Price: ₹{product.price}</li>
                                            <Sale  product={product}/>
                                            <li><a href="#" className="card-link">Buy Now</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <Rating rating={product.rating} numReview={product.numReview}/>
                                            </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))};
                
                </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is my productActions.js

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL } from "../constants/productConstants"

export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) =>{
    dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    });
    try {
        const {data} = await Axios.get('/api/products');
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload : data});
    }catch(error){
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message});
    }
}
```

Here's my productReducers.js

```
export const productListReducer = (state = {loading: true, products: [] }, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST :
            return {loading: true};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {loading: false, products: action.payload};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL :
            return {loading: false, error: action.payload};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And my productConstants.js

```
export const PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST = "PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST";
export const PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS = "PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS";
export const PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL = "PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL";
```

I've tried solving it but I can't find out what's wrong. I did `console.log(products)` instead of `const product = products.filter(prod => prod.category === props.match.params.category && prod.subcategory === props.match.params.subcategory);` in ProductScreens.jsx and also replaced the contents of `return` with `<h1></h1>` and got back the following object:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "name": "example1",
        "category": "example category1",
        "subcategory": "example subcategory1",
        "image": [
            {
                "_id": "image1",
                "name": "/images/example1.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "mainImage": "/images/example1.jpg",
        "price": "19000",
        "brand": "brand1",
        "rating": 4.5,
        "numReview": 10,
        "description": "some description for example1."
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "name": "example2",
        "category": "example category1",
        "subcategory": "example subcategory1",
        "image": [
            {
                "_id": "image2",
                "name": "/images/example2.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "mainImage": "/images/example2.jpg",
        "price": "16791",
        "salePrice": "15500",
        "brand": "brand2",
        "rating": 4.7,
        "numReview": 10,
        "description": "some description for example2."
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "name": "example",
        "category": "example category2",
        "subcategory": "example subcategory3",
        "image": [
            {
                "_id": "image3",
                "name": "/images/example3-1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "_id": "image4",
                "name": "/images/example3-2.jpg"
            },
            {
                "_id": "image5",
                "name": "/images/example3-3.jpg"
            },
            {
                "_id": "image6",
                "name": "/images/example3-4.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "mainImage": "/images/example3-1.jpg",
        "price": "8549",
        "salePrice": "7200",
        "brand": "brand3",
        "rating": 3,
        "numReview": 10,
        "description": "some description for example3."
    },
    {
        "_id": "4",
        "name": "example4",
        "category": "example category3",
        "subcategory": "example subcategory4",
        "image": [
            {
                "_id": "image7",
                "name": "/images/example4.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "mainImage": "/images/example4.jpg",
        "price": "450",
        "brand": "brand4",
        "rating": 4.5,
        "numReview": 10,
        "description": "some description for example4."
    },
    {
        "_id": "5",
        "name": "example5",
        "category": "example category1",
        "subcategory": "example subcategory2",
        "image": [
            {
                "_id": "image8",
                "name": "/images/example5.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "mainImage": "/images/example5.jpg",
        "price": "30000",
        "salePrice": "27000",
        "brand": "brand5",
        "rating": 4.5,
        "numReview": 10,
        "description": "some description for example5"
    }
]
```

Looking at the object above, filter() should work but it's not. Moreover, the above object was the same object I got when I used axios and it worked fine then. So I have no idea why it's not working anymore.
Also when I try to `console.log(products._id)` or any other property, I get the same `TypeError`. I tried `console.log(products[0])` thinking maybe I have to do that to get the first object since its an array of objects, I got `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Comment: The question you should be asking is not "why does accessing properties of an object give me an error" but "why is this value undefined". Find all assignments and mutations of this value and log after each to pinpoint the place where it becomes undefined. Then you can ask "why does this statement leave my variable undefined?"

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I asked myself that question and even though it took me a while I finally found what the issue was. It was because I returned an object which only had the `loading` property and no `products` property in the switch case statement for `PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST` in my **productReducers.js**. I added `products: []` and now it works. Took me a while cause I didn't really understand the data flow in Redux. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. I found two solutions. First, Turns out I was getting two objects before the  `PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS` action occured. In the first object, the `products` was an empty array from the initial state and in the second object which was receieved from `PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST` action, there was only a `loading` property so `products` was undefined. So I changed the `switch case` statement in **productsReducers.js** for `PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST` to `return {loading: true, products: []};` and that did the trick.
My second solution is to check if `loading` is true or false and only execute my code and render the page if `loading` is false.
I haven't been an avid programmer so I don't know best programming practices but I'm using the second solution.